# Java processbuilder and using environment variables

Tags: java, linux, process, environment-variables, processbuilder

What I want to do is I want to run a process, however because this process itself relies on environment variables, directly calling it causes error within the process. For those who are wondering what this is, it's `rake` tool. For this reason I thought maybe it's better to use `bash` and using it through `bash` would eliminate the issue. However that doesn't seem to be the case.

Here is my code:

```
public static void runPB(String directory) throws IOException {
        ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(
                "/bin/bash");
        processBuilder.directory(new File(directory));
        Process process = processBuilder.start();
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(process.getOutputStream());
        osw.write("rake routes");
        osw.close();
        printStream(process.getErrorStream());
        printStream(process.getInputStream());
    }

    public static void printStream(InputStream is) throws IOException {
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
```

I know it is environment related issue because the error that I am getting is described here [cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19061774/cannot-load-such-file-bundler-setup-loaderror)

Further I checked `processBuilder.environment()` returns less environment variables than entering `env`. I went ahead and changed the `osw.write()` line and tried `echo $GEM_HOME` there, which doesn't print anything and if I do this on my OSs bash then I get the path, I also tried other common things like `echo $SHELL` and it prints the shell location in both Java code and in bash.

So my questions are:

1) Why is my operating system's environment variables are different than the `ProcessBuilder.environment()` method?

2) Does `Process` class consider using environment variables that were given out by `ProcessBuilder.environment()`? If so then how can we add the missing ones from the operating system's level?

Comment: Have you had those environments already set before starting java process? If not then obviously ProcessBuilder might return different values. Environment variables are process specific and inherited from parent (executing) process. See `man 2 execve`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) The varaibles you see in your java process are those inheritd from the process you started the java process from. I.e. If you launch it from a shell it should have the same variables as the shell had. You need to investigate which variables are actually set before launching your Java application and why the ones you expect are not set in that context.

To answer part 2, yes, the process will be launched with the environment in `ProcessBuilder.environment()`. You can simply add things to the map returned by `ProcessBuilder.environment()`, that will extend the runtime environment:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("foo");
pb.environment().put("MY_VAR", "foobar");
```

Comment: Thank you very much! When I built the JAR it worked like a charm. Then I used bash to use my IDE and it works too.