# How To Export Path Using Java Program on Linux?

Tags: java, linux, oracle

How to export `$ORACLE_HOME` and `$PATH` in java program so oracle related commands will work?

If I execute `ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1`  and export `PATH=$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/bin` from `terminal` now if i  run Linux command `lsnrclt` status it gives result.

How can I do this using Java program so that will be in path and i can get result of `lsnrctl` status command result?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java processbuilder and using environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30574972/java-processbuilder-and-using-environment-variables)

Answer (score 2):

Java's ProcessBuilder provides a `environment()` method which will return the environment (`Map<String, String>`) of the process when started. The environment will be initialized with `System.getenv()`, but the map can be freely changed to suit your needs. So simply `Map.put` the additional environment variables you need into the Map returned by `ProcessBuilder.environment()`.

Alternatively you can export the environment variables on the shell for your Java program, in that case ProcessBuilder will pass them on to the child processes automatically.

Comment: Thank You pschichtel for your quick response. Can you please give me t code soi can test if any issue I will let you know.   The program that will export ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1 and export PATH=$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/bin

Comment: Big Thank pschichtel

Comment: @KailasKakade its iterally just `builder.environment().put("ORACLE_HOME", "/u0..............")`