# docker apache passenger: error cannot load such file bundler/setup (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, docker, passenger

I'm trying to build a docker-image with running apache (+passenger), rails and shibboleth.

Unfortunately I can't get apache + passenger running ... 
I appreciate every hint! Maybe it is a permission problem? Everything was installed as root, but obviously some processes are running as nobody (as shown in the error log).

My docker base-image is "ruby:2.0.0" (debian 8). In this image I installed apache2, apache2-threaded-dev, libapr1-dev, libaprutil1-dev via apt-get and passenger via 'gem install passenger -v 4.0.59'. After this I used passenger-install-apache2-module to install the module.

Here is the error log:

```
cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:411:in `activate_gem'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:295:in `block in run_load_path_setup_code'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:416:in `running_bundler'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:294:in `run_load_path_setup_code'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:99:in `preload_app'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:153:in `<module:App>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:28:in `<main>'

Environment (value of RAILS_ENV, RACK_ENV, WSGI_ENV, NODE_ENV and PASSENGER_APP_ENV)
  development

Ruby interpreter command
  /usr/local/bin/ruby

User and groups
  uid=65534(nobody) gid=65534(nogroup) groups=65534(nogroup)
```

Apache passenger.load:

```
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/local/bundle/gems/passenger-4.0.59/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
```

Apache passenger.conf:

```
IfModule mod_passenger.c>
  PassengerRoot /usr/local/bundle/gems/passenger-4.0.59
  PassengerDefaultRuby /usr/local/bin/ruby
</IfModule>
```

And myapp.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
#ServerName yourserver.com

# Tell Apache and Passenger where your app's 'public' directory is
DocumentRoot /var/www/myapp/public

PassengerRuby /usr/local/bin/ruby
RailsEnv development

# Relax Apache security settings
<Directory /var/www/myapp/public>
  Allow from all
  Options -MultiViews
  # Uncomment this if you're on Apache >= 2.4:
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Installed versions:

```
apache2 -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian)

ruby -v      
ruby 2.0.0p645 (2015-04-13 revision 50299)

gem -v
2.0.14

rails -v
Rails 4.0.5
```

passenger-config validate-install says "Everything looks good". And 'passenger-status':

```
Version : 4.0.59                                                               
Date    : 2015-10-13 09:03:32 +0000                                            
Instance: 5578                                                                 
----------- General information -----------                                    
Max pool size : 6                                                              
Processes     : 0                                                              
Requests in top-level queue : 0                                                

----------- Application groups -----------                                     
/var/www/myapp#default:                                                        
  App root: /var/www/myapp                                                     
  Requests in queue: 0
```

passenger-memory-stats:

```
Version: 4.0.59                                                             
Date   : 2015-10-13 09:05:31 +0000                                          

--------- Apache processes ---------                                        
PID   PPID  VMSize    Private  Name                                         
------------------------------------                                        
5578  1     83.2 MB   ?        /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start                   
5599  5578  363.5 MB  ?        /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start                   
5600  5578  491.5 MB  ?        /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start                   
### Processes: 3                                                            
### Total private dirty RSS: 0.00 MB (?)                                    


-------- Nginx processes --------                                           

### Processes: 0                                                            
### Total private dirty RSS: 0.00 MB                                        


---- Passenger processes -----                                              
PID   VMSize    Private  Name                                               
------------------------------                                              
5581  218.3 MB  ?        PassengerWatchdog                                  
5584  564.5 MB  ?        PassengerHelperAgent                               
5590  217.8 MB  ?        PassengerLoggingAgent                              
### Processes: 3                                                            
### Total private dirty RSS: 0.00 MB (?)
```

All running processes:

```
ps aux                                                                      
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND       
root         1  0.0  0.0  20300  1780 ?        Ss   08:47   0:00 bash          
root      6077  0.0  0.0  85160  3208 ?        Ss   09:11   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
root      6080  0.0  0.0 223500  2044 ?        Ssl  09:11   0:00 PassengerWatchdog
root      6083  0.0  0.0 578092  5556 ?        Sl   09:11   0:00 PassengerHelperAgent
nobody    6089  0.0  0.0 223028  5008 ?        Sl   09:11   0:00 PassengerLoggingAgent
www-data  6098  0.0  0.0 437788  5452 ?        Sl   09:11   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  6099  0.0  0.0 437780  5300 ?        Sl   09:11   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
```

**EDIT**
After 2 days searching and trying I found a solution (right after I post here my question ...):

I have to put this into my apache virtual host configuration of my app:

```
SetEnv GEM_HOME /usr/local/bundle
```

This solution was postet on https://stackoverflow.com/a/19099768/4846489

I don't know why this is necessary, because I don't have a previous installation (as stated there). This is really strange, because this environment variable is already there if I login into my docker container (docker exec -u nobody)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting `GEM_HOME` just patches over the real problem. This information here is your hint:

```
User and groups:
id=65534(nobody) gid=65534(nogroup) groups=65534(nogroup)
```

Passenger is trying to run your app as the user 'nobody'. Most likely, this is not what you meant it to do. Your gem bundle is probably installed by a different user, and the 'nobody' user probably does not have access to that installed gem bundle.

Why is Passenger running your app as 'nobody'? Because of [user sandboxing rules](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/deploy/nginx/user_sandboxing.html), most likely caused by wrong permissions on your app. You should fix that.

By the way, why are you building your own Docker image? Phusion provides its own [passenger-docker](https://github.com/phusion/passenger-docker) base image.

Comment: I'm pretty new to this stuff (docker, rails, passenger). I thought, that there is a permission problem, but I didn't know why. But thx to your link about the sandboxing rules I know why. 
Regarding passenger-docker: I know this image, but unfortunately it uses nginx. I really need apache. After your answer I reconsidered using passenger-ruby20, installing apache + shibboleth. Except the (docker) uid-problem (mounting the code from my host into /home/app causes permission problems), everything works now.