# cannot load such file -- bundler (LoadError) in linode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu-14.04, rvm, bundler, linode

I want to deploy rails app to linode cloud server. I installed ubuntu 14.04 LTS and installed ruby 2.3.0 by rvm and also installed passenger with apache2. Then I cloned my app from bitbucket and try to bundle on it but i can't. It says like this....

```
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler (LoadError)
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/bin/bundle:7:in `<main>'
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34575728/4318953

Answer (score 6):

Actually I forgot to install rails. After installing rails it is resolved automatically.

```
gem install rails
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply recheck if you have ran

```
rvm use 'your ruby version'
```

then run

```
  gem install bundler
```

that's it .

Comment: this solution does not work for fixing "`require': cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)" issue in my local configuration and I will continue search for it by doing research on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't have install bundler, I had almost precisely the same error, and was able to completely fix it simply by running:

```
gem install bundler
```

Answer (score 0):

works for me :

```
bundle exec rake rails:update:bin
```

or, in RAILS 5+

```
rails app:update:bin
```