# Rails app not loading with Passenger + Nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I have a Rails app I am trying to deploy to production. I have Passenger setup with Nginx, and looking at the Nginx logs, passenger is starting but when I try to browse to my app the error logs fills up with the following:

```
App 67160 stdout: 
App 67160 stdout: 
[ E 2017-11-17 11:06:39.5087 67125/Th age/Cor/App/Implementation.cpp:304 ]: Could not spawn process for application /var/www/vuln_frontend: An error occurred while starting up the preloader.
  Error ID: bd9a976b
  Error details saved to: /tmp/passenger-error-okz7mL.html
  Message from application: cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
  /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
  /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
  /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:456:in `activate_gem'
  /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:323:in `block in run_load_path_setup_code'
  /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:461:in `running_bundler'
  /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:322:in `run_load_path_setup_code'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:100:in `preload_app'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:156:in `<module:App>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:30:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<main>'


[ E 2017-11-17 11:06:39.5121 67125/T9 age/Cor/Con/CheckoutSession.cpp:285 ]: [Client 2-1] Cannot checkout session because a spawning error occurred. The identifier of the error is bd9a976b. Please see earlier logs for details about the error.
```

I have checked in /tmp/ but there is no `/tmp/passenger-error-okz7mL.html`
 file and my system Ruby is 2.4.2, the same as my app is using and the same as the RVM version.

I can't see where the issue lies, my gems are all up to date in the app and system.

I can load the Passenger error page but nothing else.

I have enabled riendly error pages and got the below output:

Details:

```
cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
  /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
  /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
  /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:456:in `activate_gem'
  /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:323:in `block in run_load_path_setup_code'
  /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:461:in `running_bundler'
  /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:322:in `run_load_path_setup_code'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:100:in `preload_app'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:156:in `<module:App>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:30:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<main>'

System information:

Application root
    /var/www/vuln_frontend
Environment (value of RAILS_ENV, RACK_ENV, WSGI_ENV, NODE_ENV and PASSENGER_APP_ENV)
    production
Ruby interpreter command

    /usr/bin/ruby

User and groups

    uid=99(nobody) gid=99(nobody) groups=99(nobody)

Environment variables

    PASSENGER_USE_FEEDBACK_FD = true
    SERVER_SOFTWARE = nginx/1.12.1 Phusion_Passenger/5.1.11
    PASSENGER_DEBUG_DIR = /tmp/passenger.spawn-debug.XXXXMTSagL
    USER = nobody
    LOGNAME = nobody
    SHELL = /sbin/nologin
    HOME = /
    PWD = /var/www/vuln_frontend
    IN_PASSENGER = 1
    PYTHONUNBUFFERED = 1
    NODE_PATH = /usr/share/passenger/node
    RAILS_ENV = production
    RACK_ENV = production
    WSGI_ENV = production
    NODE_ENV = production
    PASSENGER_APP_ENV = production

Ulimits

    Unknown

System metrics

    ------------- General -------------
    Kernel version    : 3.10.0-693.5.2.el7.x86_64
    Uptime            : 1d 21h 16m 17s
    Load averages     : 0.00%, 0.01%, 0.05%
    Fork rate         : unknown

    ------------- CPU -------------
    Number of CPUs    :    2
    Average CPU usage :   0%  --   0% user,   0% nice,   0% system, 100% idle
      CPU 1           :   0%  --   0% user,   0% nice,   0% system, 100% idle
      CPU 2           :   0%  --   0% user,   0% nice,   0% system, 100% idle
    I/O pressure      :   0%
      CPU 1           :   0%
      CPU 2           :   0%
    Interference from other VMs:   0%
      CPU 1                    :   0%
      CPU 2                    :   0%

    ------------- Memory -------------
    RAM total         :   1823 MB
    RAM used          :    543 MB (30%)
    RAM free          :   1279 MB
    Swap total        :   2047 MB
    Swap used         :      0 MB (0%)
    Swap free         :   2047 MB
    Swap in           : unknown
    Swap out          : unknown

General Ruby interpreter information

    RUBY_VERSION = 2.0.0
    RUBY_PLATFORM = x86_64-linux
    RUBY_ENGINE = ruby
    RubyGems version = 2.0.14.1
    RubyGems paths = ["/.gem/ruby", "/usr/share/gems", "/usr/local/share/gems"]

Ruby configuration (RbConfig::CONFIG)

    DESTDIR = 
    MAJOR = 2
    MINOR = 0
    TEENY = 0
    PATCHLEVEL = 648
    INSTALL = /usr/bin/install -c
    EXEEXT = 
    prefix = /usr
    ruby_install_name = ruby
    RUBY_INSTALL_NAME = ruby
    RUBY_SO_NAME = ruby
    exec = exec
    ruby_pc = ruby.pc
    PACKAGE = ruby
    BUILTIN_TRANSSRCS =  newline.c
    USE_RUBYGEMS = YES
    MANTYPE = doc
    NROFF = /usr/bin/nroff
    OPTIONAL_PRELUDES = ./abrt_prelude.rb
    vendorarchhdrdir = /usr/include/vendor_ruby/x86_64-linux
    sitearchhdrdir = /usr/include/site_ruby/x86_64-linux
    rubyarchhdrdir = /usr/include
    vendorhdrdir = /usr/include/vendor_ruby
    sitehdrdir = /usr/include/site_ruby
    rubyhdrdir = /usr/include
    UNIVERSAL_INTS = 
    UNIVERSAL_ARCHNAMES = 
    configure_args =  '--build=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' '--host=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' '--program-prefix=' '--disable-dependency-tracking' '--prefix=/usr' '--exec-prefix=/usr' '--bindir=/usr/bin' '--sbindir=/usr/sbin' '--sysconfdir=/etc' '--datadir=/usr/share' '--includedir=/usr/include' '--libdir=/usr/lib64' '--libexecdir=/usr/libexec' '--localstatedir=/var' '--sharedstatedir=/var/lib' '--mandir=/usr/share/man' '--infodir=/usr/share/info' '--with-rubylibprefix=/usr/share/ruby' '--with-rubyarchprefix=/usr/lib64/ruby' '--with-sitedir=/usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby' '--with-sitearchdir=/usr/local/lib64/ruby/site_ruby' '--with-vendordir=/usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby' '--with-vendorarchdir=/usr/lib64/ruby/vendor_ruby' '--with-rubyhdrdir=/usr/include' '--with-rubyarchhdrdir=/usr/include' '--with-sitearchhdrdir=/usr/include/site_ruby/x86_64-linux' '--with-vendorarchhdrdir=/usr/include/vendor_ruby/x86_64-linux' '--with-rubygemsdir=/usr/share/rubygems' '--with-ruby-pc=ruby.pc' '--disable-rpath' '--enable-shared' '--with-ruby-version=' '--enable-multiarch' '--with-prelude=./abrt_prelude.rb' 'build_alias=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' 'host_alias=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' 'CFLAGS=-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches   -m64 -mtune=generic' 'LDFLAGS=-Wl,-z,relro ' 'CXXFLAGS=-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches   -m64 -mtune=generic'
    rubygemsdir = /usr/share/rubygems
    vendorarchdir = /usr/lib64/ruby/vendor_ruby
    vendorlibdir = /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/
    vendordir = /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby
    sitearchdir = /usr/local/lib64/ruby/site_ruby
    sitelibdir = /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/
    sitedir = /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby
    rubyarchdir = /usr/lib64/ruby/
    rubylibdir = /usr/share/ruby/
    ruby_version = 
    sitearch = x86_64-linux
    arch = x86_64-linux
    sitearchincludedir = /usr/include/x86_64-linux
    archincludedir = /usr/include/x86_64-linux
    sitearchlibdir = /usr/lib64/x86_64-linux
    archlibdir = /usr/lib64/x86_64-linux
    RI_BASE_NAME = ri
    ridir = /usr/share/ri
    rubysitearchprefix = /usr/lib64/x86_64-linux/ruby
    rubyarchprefix = /usr/lib64/ruby
    rubylibprefix = /usr/share/ruby
    MAKEFILES = Makefile
    PLATFORM_DIR = 
    THREAD_MODEL = pthread
    SYMBOL_PREFIX = 
    EXPORT_PREFIX = 
    COMMON_HEADERS = 
    COMMON_MACROS = 
    COMMON_LIBS = 
    MAINLIBS = 
    ENABLE_SHARED = yes
    DLDLIBS =  -lc
    SOLIBS = -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm 
    LIBRUBYARG_SHARED = -lruby
    LIBRUBYARG_STATIC = -lruby-static
    LIBRUBYARG = -lruby
    LIBRUBY = libruby.so.2.0.0
    LIBRUBY_ALIASES = libruby.so.2.0 libruby.so
    LIBRUBY_SO = libruby.so.2.0.0
    LIBRUBY_A = libruby-static.a
    RUBYW_INSTALL_NAME = 
    rubyw_install_name = 
    LIBRUBY_DLDFLAGS = -Wl,-soname,libruby.so.2.0 
    LIBRUBY_LDSHARED = gcc -shared
    EXTDLDFLAGS = 
    EXTLDFLAGS = 
    strict_warnflags = -ansi -std=iso9899:199409
    warnflags = -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration
    debugflags = -ggdb3
    optflags = -O3 -fno-fast-math
    cxxflags =  -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration
    cflags =  -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration
    cppflags = 
    NULLCMD = :
    DLNOBJ = dln.o
    INSTALLDOC = all
    CAPITARGET = nodoc
    RDOCTARGET = rdoc
    DTRACE_GLOMMED_OBJ = ruby-glommed.o
    DTRACE_OBJ = probes.o
    DTRACE_EXT = d
    EXECUTABLE_EXTS = 
    ARCHFILE = 
    LIBRUBY_RELATIVE = no
    EXTOUT = .ext
    RUNRUBY_COMMAND = $(MINIRUBY) $(srcdir)/tool/runruby.rb --extout=.ext $(RUNRUBYOPT)
    PREP = miniruby
    BTESTRUBY = $(MINIRUBY)
    CROSS_COMPILING = no
    TEST_RUNNABLE = yes
    setup = Setup
    EXTSTATIC = 
    STRIP = strip -S -x
    TRY_LINK = 
    LIBPATHENV = LD_LIBRARY_PATH
    RPATHFLAG = 
    LIBPATHFLAG =  -L%s
    LINK_SO = 
    LIBEXT = a
    DLEXT2 = 
    DLEXT = so
    LDSHAREDXX = g++ -shared
    LDSHARED = gcc -shared
    CCDLFLAGS = -fPIC
    STATIC = 
    ARCH_FLAG = -m64
    DLDFLAGS = 
    ALLOCA = 
    codesign = 
    POSTLINK = :
    WERRORFLAG = -Werror
    CHDIR = cd -P
    RMALL = rm -fr
    RMDIRS = rmdir --ignore-fail-on-non-empty -p
    RMDIR = rmdir --ignore-fail-on-non-empty
    CP = cp
    RM = rm -f
    PKG_CONFIG = pkg-config
    PYTHON = 
    DOXYGEN = 
    DOT = 
    DTRACE = dtrace
    MAKEDIRS = /usr/bin/mkdir -p
    MKDIR_P = /usr/bin/mkdir -p
    INSTALL_DATA = /usr/bin/install -c -m 644
    INSTALL_SCRIPT = /usr/bin/install -c
    INSTALL_PROGRAM = /usr/bin/install -c
    SET_MAKE = 
    LN_S = ln -s
    NM = nm
    DLLWRAP = 
    WINDRES = 
    OBJCOPY = :
    OBJDUMP = objdump
    ASFLAGS = 
    AS = as
    AR = ar
    RANLIB = ranlib
    try_header = 
    COUTFLAG = -o 
    OUTFLAG = -o 
    CPPOUTFILE = -o conftest.i
    GNU_LD = yes
    LD = ld
    GCC = yes
    EGREP = /usr/bin/grep -E
    GREP = /usr/bin/grep
    CPP = gcc -E
    CXXFLAGS = -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -mtune=generic
    CXX = g++
    OBJEXT = o
    CPPFLAGS =   
    LDFLAGS = -L. -Wl,-z,relro -fstack-protector -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic
    CFLAGS = -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -mtune=generic -fPIC
    CC = gcc
    NACL_SDK_VARIANT = 
    NACL_SDK_ROOT = 
    NACL_TOOLCHAIN = 
    target_os = linux
    target_vendor = redhat
    target_cpu = x86_64
    target = x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
    host_os = linux-gnu
    host_vendor = redhat
    host_cpu = x86_64
    host = x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
    RUBY_VERSION_NAME = ruby-
    RUBYW_BASE_NAME = rubyw
    RUBY_BASE_NAME = ruby
    build_os = linux-gnu
    build_vendor = redhat
    build_cpu = x86_64
    build = x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
    RUBY_RELEASE_DATE = 2015-12-16
    RUBY_PROGRAM_VERSION = 2.0.0
    target_alias = 
    host_alias = x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
    build_alias = x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
    LIBS = -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm 
    ECHO_T = 
    ECHO_N = -n
    ECHO_C = 
    DEFS = 
    mandir = /usr/share/man
    localedir = /usr/share/locale
    libdir = /usr/lib64
    psdir = /usr/share/doc/ruby
    pdfdir = /usr/share/doc/ruby
    dvidir = /usr/share/doc/ruby
    htmldir = /usr/share/doc/ruby
    infodir = /usr/share/info
    docdir = /usr/share/doc/ruby
    oldincludedir = /usr/include
    includedir = /usr/include
    localstatedir = /var
    sharedstatedir = /var/lib
    sysconfdir = /etc
    datadir = /usr/share
    datarootdir = /usr/share
    libexecdir = /usr/libexec
    sbindir = /usr/sbin
    bindir = /usr/bin
    exec_prefix = /usr
    PACKAGE_URL = 
    PACKAGE_BUGREPORT = 
    PACKAGE_STRING = 
    PACKAGE_VERSION = 
    PACKAGE_TARNAME = 
    PACKAGE_NAME = 
    PATH_SEPARATOR = :
    SHELL = /bin/sh
    archdir = /usr/lib64/ruby/
    topdir = /usr/lib64/ruby

Ruby load path ($LOAD_PATH)

    /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby
    /usr/local/lib64/ruby/site_ruby
    /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby
    /usr/lib64/ruby/vendor_ruby
    /usr/share/rubygems
    /usr/share/ruby
    /usr/lib64/ruby/

Ruby loaded libraries ($LOADED_FEATURES)

    enumerator.so
    /usr/lib64/ruby/enc/encdb.so
    /usr/lib64/ruby/enc/trans/transdb.so
    /usr/lib64/ruby/rbconfig.rb
    /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/compatibility.rb
    /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/defaults.rb
    /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/deprecate.rb
    /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/errors.rb
    /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/version.rb
    /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/requirement.rb
    /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/platform.rb
    /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/specification.rb
    /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/exceptions.rb
    /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/defaults/operating_system.rb
    /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb
    /usr/share/ruby/thread.rb
    /usr/share/ruby/monitor.rb
    /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb
    /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems.rb
    /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/path_support.rb
    /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/dependency.rb
    /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger.rb
    /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/constants.rb
    /usr/lib64/ruby/etc.so
    /usr/share/ruby/fileutils.rb
    /usr/share/ruby/tmpdir.rb
    /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/utils/tmpio.rb
    /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/platform_info.rb
    /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/platform_info/operating_system.rb
    /usr/lib64/ruby/vendor_ruby/passenger_native_support.so
    /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/native_support.rb
    /usr/lib64/ruby/socket.so
    /usr/share/ruby/socket.rb
    /usr/lib64/ruby/pathname.so
    /usr/share/ruby/pathname.rb
    /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/ruby_core_enhancements.rb
    /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/ruby_core_io_enhancements.rb
    /usr/share/ruby/base64.rb
    /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/utils.rb
    /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/preloader_shared_helpers.rb
    /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/public_api.rb
    /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/debug_logging.rb
    /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/platform_info/ruby.rb
    /usr/share/ruby/shellwords.rb
    /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/utils/shellwords.rb
    /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb
    /usr/lib64/ruby/fcntl.so
    /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/message_channel.rb
    /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/message_client.rb
    /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/utils/native_support_utils.rb
    /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/utils/unseekable_socket.rb
    /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb
    /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb
    /usr/lib64/ruby/stringio.so
    /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/utils/tee_input.rb
    /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb
    /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/vendor/union_station_hooks_core/lib/union_station_hooks_core/version.rb
    /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/vendor/union_station_hooks_core/lib/union_station_hooks_core.rb
    /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/vendor/union_station_hooks_rails/lib/union_station_hooks_rails/version.rb
    /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/vendor/union_station_hooks_rails/lib/union_station_hooks_rails.rb
```

Comment: Sorry my bad! Was commenting on another question. Have you installed bundler gem ?

Comment: Yes, using `gem install bundler`

Comment: Okay, are you able to do `bundle exec rails c production` ? are there any error ?

Comment: If I run it in my app folder I get `[root@localhost vuln_frontend]# bundle exec rails c production
Running via Spring preloader in process 122252
Loading production environment (Rails 5.1.4)
2.4.2 :001 > 
`

Comment: Pls have a look at this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19061774/cannot-load-such-file-bundler-setup-loaderror  its mostly likely that passenger cant locate bundler.

Comment: my `$GEM_PATH` is /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2@global which does have a subfolder of gems which does have bundler

Answer (score 0):

Passenger is using `/usr/bin/ruby` and you want it to use an RVM Ruby. You need to tell Passenger which Ruby command it should use to run your app, because there are multiple Ruby interpreters on your system. Please run `passenger-config about ruby-command` to find out which Ruby interpreter you are using. For example:

```
passenger-config about ruby-command
passenger-config was invoked through the following Ruby interpreter:
  Command: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/wrappers/ruby
  Version: ruby 2.3.3p85 (2015-02-26 revision 49769) [x86_64-linux]
  ...
```

Please take note of the path after "Command" (in this example, `/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/wrappers/ruby`). You need to set the `passenger_ruby` config option to this path.

https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/deploy/nginx/deploy/ruby/#determine_ruby_command