# RVM after install ruby 2.5.1 got error require': cannot load such file -- bundler/setup

Tags: ruby, rvm, bundler

After install ruby 2.5.1 using RVM (lasted), when i run rails s, i got error bellow:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    5: from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
    4: from bin/rails:3:in `require_relative'
    3: from /Users/thiensubs/Documents/super-control/config/boot.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    2: from /Users/thiensubs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:39:in `require'
    1: from /Users/thiensubs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `rescue in require'
/Users/thiensubs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
```

Any body can help me?

Comment: have you tried with this solution?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19061774/cannot-load-such-file-bundler-setup-loaderror

Comment: absolutely, i tried.

Comment: @ThienSuBS even the second answer?  To me this sounds like Bundler is not installed. https://stackoverflow.com/a/34575728/8463613

Answer (score 1):

You need to check your `gem list` and see if bundler is installed, then `bundle install (--without production)`

Comment: Yes, i'm sure about that, because when i downgrade ruby back 2.5.0, it is working.

Answer (score 1):

Check that you don't have a .ruby-version file with just "2.5" in it. Switching mine to "2.5.1" fixed this.

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me

```
gem update --system
```