# LoadError issue with rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to rails and I am having a problem with starting a web server. After I type in "rails server" in my terminal, I see the following error.

[image]

How can I fix this? I tried gem pristine stuff as suggested but it didn't work.

Comment: I think there is an issue with the bundler. can you check this similar question `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19061774/cannot-load-such-file-bundler-setup-loaderror`

Answer (score 0):

Try `gem install bundler` and install dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

If bundler is not install, install bundler with command: `gem install bundler`

Install all gem with command: `bundle install` or `bundle`.

Then Configure your database to the database.yml.

Create new database: `rake db:create`
Then start rails server.

`rails server` or `rails s`