# Ruby on Rails server setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, passenger

I'm trying to deploy ROR application to Ubuntu server(EC2).
I'm using following versions:

- Ruby : 2.4.0p0
- Rails : 4.2.8
- Bundler : 1.17.3

*For some reason my colleague has created a gemset instead of normal setup.

gem env is:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.6.8
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.4.0 (2016-12-24 patchlevel 0) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@myrepo
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/ubuntu/.gem/ruby/2.4.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@myrepo/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /home/ubuntu/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@myrepo
     - /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@myrepo/bin
     - /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/bin
     - /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/bin
     - /home/ubuntu/.rvm/bin
     - /home/ubuntu/bin
     - /home/ubuntu/.local/bin
     - /usr/local/sbin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /usr/bin
     - /sbin
     - /bin
     - /usr/games
     - /usr/local/games
     - /snap/bin
```

I did the setup of nginx and passenger and set the root paths.

- nginx version: nginx/1.17.3
- Phusion Passenger : 6.0.4

I believe there is nothing wrong with nginx and passenger's settings but I'm getting following error:
The Phusion Passenger application server tried to start the web application. But the application itself (and not Passenger) encountered an internal error.

Error details:

```
cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:363:in `activate_gem'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:221:in `block in run_load_path_setup_code'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:527:in `running_bundler'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:220:in `run_load_path_setup_code'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:91:in `preload_app'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:189:in `block in <module:App>'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:380:in `run_block_and_record_step_progress'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:188:in `<module:App>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:30:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<main>'
```

The stdout/stderr output of the subprocess so far is:

```
 [passenger_native_support.so] trying to compile for the current user (nobody) and Ruby interpreter...
     (set PASSENGER_COMPILE_NATIVE_SUPPORT_BINARY=0 to disable)
     Warning: compilation didn't succeed. To learn why, read this file:
     /tmp/passenger_native_support-18gfm98.log
 [passenger_native_support.so] finding downloads for the current Ruby interpreter...
     (set PASSENGER_DOWNLOAD_NATIVE_SUPPORT_BINARY=0 to disable)
     Could not download https://github.com/phusion/passenger/releases/download/release-6.0.4/rubyext-ruby-2.4.0-x86_64-linux.tar.gz: The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
     Trying next mirror...
     Could not download https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/binaries/passenger/by_release/6.0.4/rubyext-ruby-2.4.0-x86_64-linux.tar.gz: The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
     Trying next mirror...
     Could not download https://s3.amazonaws.com/phusion-passenger/binaries/passenger/by_release/6.0.4/rubyext-ruby-2.4.0-x86_64-linux.tar.gz: The requested URL returned error: 403 Forbidden
 [passenger_native_support.so] will not be used (can't compile or download) 
  --> Passenger will still operate normally.
Error: The application encountered the following error: cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
    /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:363:in `activate_gem'
    /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:221:in `block in run_load_path_setup_code'
    /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:527:in `running_bundler'
    /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:220:in `run_load_path_setup_code'
    /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:91:in `preload_app'
    /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:189:in `block in <module:App>'
    /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:380:in `run_block_and_record_step_progress'
    /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:188:in `<module:App>'
    /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:30:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
    /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<main>'
```

Does anybody has any idea?

Comment: What is the output if you run `bundler -v` . Possible answer here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19061774/cannot-load-such-file-bundler-setup-loaderror

Comment: @RockwellRice Bundler version 1.17.3

Comment: @RockwellRice Sorry I'm using nginx and it does not manage backend's processes like apache does so there is no way to set environment path.

Answer (score 0):

passenger is trying to download a file that does not exist.

try with ruby 2.4.6 since that version is listed on the github release page

https://github.com/phusion/passenger/releases/

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the point is in that you're setting up and testing rvm/ruby under `ubuntu` user, but nginx server is running under some other user (which does not have rvm configured, at least in the session in which the daemon runs)

RVM has ability to create a wrapper, that will set correct paths and gemset (if needed):

```sh
rvm alias create ruby_for_my_app ruby-2.4.0@myrepo
```

and then use `/home/ubuntu/.rvm/wrappers/ruby_for_my_app/ruby` in `passenger_ruby` nginx config directive (remember to reload it after changing)

Comment: Why do I have to create a gemset? I have not installed any other versionof ruby, rails or bundler.

Comment: @VishwasTrivedi gemset is not necessary, it is in example in case you have one