# Debugging Dokku deploy error with Ruby on Rails (I'm lost + inexperienced)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, dokku

I have a Rails app running on the edge branch (not sure why I decided to do do that...). I am getting this error when I run `git push dokku master`.

```
[stuff above this is working fine I think]
=====> Processing deployment checks
       No CHECKS file found. Simple container checks will be performed.
       For more efficient zero downtime deployments, create a CHECKS file. See http://dokku.viewdocs.io/dokku/deployment/zero-downtime-deploys/ for examples
-----> Attempting pre-flight checks (web.1)
       Waiting for 10 seconds ...
22d6175eec2ca12..............................[hidden by me]5c23bb5fa
remote: App container failed to start!!
=====> taaalk web container output:
       > taaalk_edge@0.1.0 start
       > webpack-dev-server --hot
       /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
        from /app/bin/webpack-dev-server:10:in `<main>'
       > taaalk_edge@0.1.0 start
       > webpack-dev-server --hot
       /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
        from /app/bin/webpack-dev-server:10:in `<main>'
       > taaalk_edge@0.1.0 start
       > webpack-dev-server --hot
       /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
        from /app/bin/webpack-dev-server:10:in `<main>'
       > taaalk_edge@0.1.0 start
       > webpack-dev-server --hot
       /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
        from /app/bin/webpack-dev-server:10:in `<main>'
       > taaalk_edge@0.1.0 start
       > webpack-dev-server --hot
       /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
        from /app/bin/webpack-dev-server:10:in `<main>'
=====> end taaalk web container output
To taaalk.co:taaalk
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'dokku@taaalk.co:taaalk'
```

When I log into my server and go to user/lib there is no ruby directory. My options are:

```
accountsservice  dpkg           gnupg            kernel  mime                 openssh     python3.6  sftp-server          sysctl.d    tc
apt              environment.d  gnupg2           klibc   modules-load.d       os-release  python3.7  shim                 systemd     tmpfiles.d
binfmt.d         file           groff            linux   networkd-dispatcher  pm-utils    python3.8  software-properties  sysusers.d  ubuntu-release-upgrader
cloud-init       gcc            grub             locale  nginx                python2.7   rsyslog    ssl                  tar         valgrind
dbus-1.0         git-core       initramfs-tools  man-db  node_modules         python3     sasl2      sudo                 tasksel     x86_64-linux-gnu
```

Additionally, the Ruby version I have locally is `ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [x86_64-darwin19]`

I'm not sure where to begin debugging! If anyone can help me find the right direction that would be great.

Comment: Did you try this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/34575728/5841310

Comment: I don't think I'm getting gem as a function I can run! But will try later. Does it matter that if I do ruby -v in my server it says the command ruby is not recognised by my server

Comment: Do you know if there is a folder I should run it in? (My root directory orrrr?)

Answer (score 0):

try `git push dokku main:master`