# Cannot run `bundle install`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

So the other day I ran into an extreme hard disk issue and had to manually delete my `.gem` folder. I attempted to rebuild the gems for my apps by going into my project folders to run `bundle install` ... I am unfortunately running into this error:

```
/home/xxx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler (LoadError)
    from /home/xxx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /usr/bin/bundle:7:in `<main>'
```

By the way, line 54 of kernel_require.rb is `return gem_original_require(path)`:

```
if Gem::Specification.unresolved_deps.empty? then
  RUBYGEMS_ACTIVATION_MONITOR.exit
  return gem_original_require(path)
end
```

Comment: Please try to remove 'Gemfile.lock' then try to do 'bundle install'

Comment: Just tried that. Same error unfortunately

Comment: Can you try install bundler gem using `gem install bundler`

Comment: I will add it as a answer please accept.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Since you deleted the ".gem" folder, your Bundler gem is also not present.

Try reinstalling the Bundler gem first by using

```
gem install bundler
```

then you can run

```
bundle install
```

Comment: Also possibly related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17334359/new-to-ruby-and-am-having-trouble-with-load-path